# Proof of quantization of magnetic charge of monopoles using homotopy groups

Tags: mathematical-physics, gauge-theory, topology, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-monopole

Suppose we place a monopole at the origin $\{{\bf 0}\}$, and the gauge field is well-definded in region $\mathbb R^3-\{0\}$ which is homomorphic to a sphere $S^2$.

Then the total manifold is $U(1)$ fibers attached to base $S^2$. We may ask how many types of "phase texture" are there on a sphere?

Then I use $\pi_2 (U(1)) = \pi_2(S^1)$ since we established the map $S^2\mapsto U(1) \sim S^1$.

But [$\pi_2 (S^1) = 0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#.CF.802.28S1.29_.3D_0) not $\mathbb Z$! Where I got wrong?
According to the famous book [Topology and Geometry for Physicists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486478521), the correct formula should be $$ \pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb Z.$$ Why $\pi_1$ instead of $\pi_2$?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb R^3-\{0\}$ is *homeomorphic* to $S^2$?  And if so, notice that the first space is non-compact (in particular it is not a bounded subset of $\mathbb R^3$) while $S^2$ is compact, so this statement alone is not true.

Comment: Maybe "homotopically equivalent to" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OP is classifying with $\pi_2 (G)$ [where the gauge group here is $G=U(1)$], is the globally$^1$ defined gauge transformations $g: M\to G$. This is typically not what we want to calculate.

When discussing the [Dirac monopole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) physicists are instead interested in classifying inequivalent configurations of the dynamical variable of the theory, i.e. the gauge potential $A$. More precisely, in the Wu-Yang/bundle picture (which avoids the use of a [Dirac string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_string)), we consider the associated vector bundle $$T^{*}M\otimes \mathfrak{g}~\to~ M,$$ where $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{u}(1)$ is the corresponding Lie algebra. It is implicitly understood that the gauge potentials $A_{\alpha}: U_{\alpha}\to \mathfrak{g}$ are defined on local charts $U_{\alpha}\subset M$ with $\cup_{\alpha}U_{\alpha}=M$. Moreover it is implicitly understood that two local sections $A_{\alpha}: U_{\alpha}\to \mathfrak{g}$ and $A_{\beta}: U_{\beta}\to \mathfrak{g}$ are connected via local [gauge transformations](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gauge+transformation) $g_{\alpha\beta}: U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta} \to G$ in the overlaps $U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta}$.

It turns out that we are therefore interested in counting maps from the equatorial overlap region $S^1$ to $G$, i.e. $\pi_1 (G)$, as twistor59 explains in his answer.

--

$^1$ The underlying space manifold for the Dirac monopole is $M=\mathbb{R}^3\backslash\{\bf 0\}$, which is [homotopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence) [equivalent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyEquivalence.html) (but not homeomorhic) to $S^2$. We have removed the origin, since the Dirac monopole is singular there. [The ['t Hooft-Polyakov monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27t_Hooft%E2%80%93Polyakov_monopole) are regular in the full space $\mathbb{R}^3$, but we will not discuss these monopoles in this answer.]

Answer (score 3):

You want to specify how much "twist" there is in a $U(1)$ (i.e. effectively $S^1$) bundle over $S^2$.  If you cover $S^2$ with a North and South patch, then the transition region is topologically $S^1$ so the bundle is classified by maps $S^1$ to $U(1)$, i.e. you want $\pi_1(U(1))=\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: I see. Does it apply to all closesd 2D surfaces with non-zero curvature? e.g. a $T^2$? In this case the TKNN invariant also reads $\pi_1 (U(1)) = \mathbb Z$

Comment: $T^2$ means $S^1XS^1$?  If so, then yes, I think in this case the circle bundles are classified by $H^2(M;\mathbb{Z})$ which is again the integers - the Euler class.

Comment: Yet, TKNN invariant are known to be first "Chern" numbers.